# How to simplify if statements when comparing multiple strings

Tags: java

Is there a way I can make this code shorter?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String reply = scan.nextLine();

if (reply.equals("rock") || reply.equals("paper") || reply.equals("scissors")){
    /**/
}
```

Comment: @Jonasz Next time just post that sort of thing as an answer, mate.

Comment: Thanks, I was in a hurry and I don't like posting answers that I'm not happy with. Posted it now with some extended description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easiest to go with such code:

```java
Set.of("rock", "paper", "scissors").contains(reply)
```

The `Set` could also be stored as an instance field in the class, where it could be parameterized during object creation if needed or as a constant (`static final`) field with a meaningful name such as (for example) `CORRECT_GAME_INPUTS` and thanks to that the whole `if` would look like this:

```java
if (CORRECT_GAME_INPUTS.contains(reply)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.nextLine();
String[] as = s.split("\\s");
String opt = "rock paper scissors" ;
for(String sl:as){
    if(opt.contains(sl)){
    //blah..blah....
    System.out.println("True");
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails if they type `ape`.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of comparing a list which you cannot add or remove in the program shall be this way, as well as to cater for the OR operand in a single line:

```
List<String> conditions = Arrays.asList("rock","paper","scissors");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String reply = scan.nextLine();

if (conditions.contains(reply)){
    /**/ 
}
```

This way it is cleaner and more maintainable in the long run

Comment: In case of bigger collections it's better to use a `Set` in such case, because it's more efficient just to call the `contains` method. See for example [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashset-arraylist-contains-performance).

Comment: @Jonasz There's a specific reason I used Arrays.asList instead of a set here, this is due to the list of conditions should not be modifiable by any other function. Now through your link i see it is doing a contain operations for a set vs list of size of 1000. In this case I would definitely try to consider using streams and filter to carry such an operation.

Comment: `Set.of()` produces an immutable collection as well.

Comment: `Set.of()` is limited in terms of arguments.  But the ability to protect against modification  is easily  controlled.  Use a method to access a privately declared set via your own `contains` method.  You can also use `Collections.unmodifiableSet` to protect the contents of the set.  But the bottom line is that using a `Set` is, imo, the preferred solution in this application.

Answer (score -3):

I would create a string with all the options.  Then check to see if the reply is in the string.

```
String reply = scan.nextLine();
String options = "rock paper scissors";
if (options.contains(reply)){ }
```

Comment: This fails if a line contains `rock paper`.

Comment: Or contains `ape`.